# Is there a plugin to turn comments into structured reviews

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

I am looking for a plugin that adds a star rating to a comment, transforming the comment into a user review.

[Here is an example.](http://demo.dailywp.com/reviewengine/product/apple-macbook-pro-2010) I have bought this theme but it is a theme, not a plugin and really limits the use case of wordpress.

I have also looked at GD Star Rating, but it is designed to let user review comments and posts, what I am looking for is turning comments into reviews, where the review include both some text and a rating.  IE. The comment is a review of a product (Amazon style) not the comment can be reviewed by readers (GD Star Rating style).

Is it possible to do this?

---

Update: the review-it theme which is using GD star is really close to what I want, but it doesn't show the reviews with the comments, it only shows the aggregate of the user reviews.
Example here:
http://botchweed.com/review/call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3-review/

---

Upage:  It turns out that review-it theme does support this, but only if you have one set of reviews.  They have an option on the review page called "Show user reviews" or something liek that.   You can see it [here](http://ghostpool.com/wordpress/reviewit/review/quisque-ultricies-consequat/):

Comment: Check this out: http://pmg.co/adding-extra-fields-to-wordpress-comments and a working example: https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/mrg-wordpress-store/blob/master/store-plugin/includes/front-reviews.php Not exactly what you want, but it can be done with comment meta and adding a few fields to the comment form.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help...

I know LiveFyre is a realtime commenting plugin that includes user ratings in a 5star format.
http://www.livefyre.com/features/

Comment: this uses its own database, so that would makes things a little difficult to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

You could integrate this php script: http://colorpowered.com/colorrating/

To create a combined user review number from all the individual reviews would take a bit more coding.